# Change Variables Depending on Selected Set of Checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a set of checkbox which has different values depending on the combination of selected boxes, but the code I made didn't work, I was thinking maybe the location of my && sign is not in proper position but I don't know where exactly I can put it to run the code.

Here is the html code:

```
<form role="form" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" onclick="changevalue()">
    <input type="checkbox" id="f1">Full Front
    <input type="checkbox" id="b1">Full Back
    <input type="checkbox" id="f2">Pocket
</form>

<input type="number" id="checkboxResult">
```

And here is the script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function changevalue(form){
        var chkboxvalue = 0;
            if (document.getElementById('f1').checked) &&
            if (document.getElementById('b1').checked) {
                chkboxvalue = 2.2;
            };

            if (document.getElementById('f2').checked) &&
            if (document.getElementById('b1').checked) {
                chkboxvalue = 1.7;
            };

        document.getElementById('checkboxResult').value = chkboxvalue;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of && does not require an additional `if`:

```
function changevalue(form){
    var chkboxvalue = 0;
        if ((document.getElementById('f1').checked) &&
           (document.getElementById('b1').checked)) {
            chkboxvalue = 2.2;
        };

        if ((document.getElementById('f2').checked) &&
           (document.getElementById('b1').checked)) {
            chkboxvalue = 1.7;
        };

    document.getElementById('checkboxResult').value = chkboxvalue;
}
```

Or more generically:
Do this:
`if (a && b){...}`
and not this:
`if (a) && if (b){...}`

Comment: can you kindly explain it a bit more? I'm really confused.

Comment: Inside a single if statement you can put as many conditions as you want using && (logical AND) and || (logical OR).  The way you originally wrote the code actually generates a syntax error.

Comment: oh I see, I checked it again and it works fine. Thank you so much.